# ReactJS map function not working on a lightbox gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the first time I'm using map() function on react and I was trying to use it in a lightbox image gallery made of JQuery (CDN).

**It perfectly runs and opens the lightbox without a map (just a single image) as in this code:**

```
<li
className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
data-src={data[0]?.img}
data-sub-html={`<h4>${data[0]?.title}</h4><p>${data[0]?.desc}</p>`}
>
    <a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
        <img className="img-responsive" src={data[0]?.img} alt="Thumb-1" />
    </a>
</li>
```

**But with the map() it shows the images (so the data has been sent I think), but the lightbox isn't popup when click.**

```
{data.map((item,i)=>(
<li
key={i++}
className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
data-src={item.img}
data-sub-html={`<h4>${item.title}</h4><p>${item.desc}</p>`}
>
    <a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
        <img className="img-responsive" src={item.img} alt="Thumb-1" />
    </a>
</li> ))}
```

Here the full component : https://www.codepile.net/pile/q8526QDd

**Can anyone help me to fix this?** please this is the 1st time I'm asking a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: I need more information about your code. This is not enough.

Comment: @S.Hesam sorry, i'm using firebase to get data to 'data' state here's the react component https://www.codepile.net/pile/q8526QDd i commented the special things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach,

```
<ul>
      {
        data.map((item)=>(
          <li
          className="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
          data-src={item?.img}
          data-sub-html={`<h4>${item?.title}</h4><p>${item?.desc}</p>`}
          >
            <a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
             <img className="img-responsive" src={item?.img} alt="Thumb-1" />
           </a>
          </li> ))
        }
  </ul>
```

Comment: are you getting any error in the console? Please include the `data` value

Comment: Yes, i forgot it.. 1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. here the component https://www.codepile.net/pile/q8526QDd

Comment: for this warning you can add a `key ` property to `li` element. If possible attach the result you are getting from the firebase.

Comment: i added a key then the warning disappeared but still the lightbox not opening, here's the console.log(data) https://www.codepile.net/pile/4GeQzzGr